# Can't post from app - reports false negative feedback

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

When I post to my wall from my app using Android Facebook SDK, I get message box on screen saying:

> **Post blocked to prev...** - The content you are trying to share has
>   received a large proportion of negative feedback from Facebook users.

However, insights of my app on FB show no negative feedback whatsoever, and ten's of thousands of impressions this year. I am now getting negative comments on my app from users wanting to share stuff to their friends, but can't!

Other users may have similar issues when developing apps, hence why this question is not off-topic. So perhaps a FB engineer can look into this I include my app id: 285845051491947 (Mood Meter)

What is going on here, why can't my users post stuff to their walls?

Code:

```
  if (facebook.isSessionValid())
  {
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
     params.putString("name", "Mood Meter for Android");
     params.putString("link", "https://www.facebook.com/MoodMeter");
     params.putString("caption", caption);
     params.putString("picture", "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15008117/moodmeter/green_happy2.png");

     params.putString("description", desc+"Obtained from Mood Meter for android - download it today to see how happy you really are!");
     facebook.dialog(context, "feed", params, new DialogListener ()
     {

        ....
```

Comment: "Closed as off topic"?  This is very frustrating. I am the developer of the app. This is a developer question.  I posted a bug on Facebook but it was closed as invalid with no explanation.  I am left with no-where to go, just unhappy users (who are unhappy with the Facebook part of the app only!).

Comment: Also, FB cannot be contacted directly regarding issues like this, and they closed down their forum in favour of a stackoverflow Q&A. Where do you suggest I post this question if not here? Please help! Thanks.

Comment: The message is about the _content_ you are trying to share, not about shares made through your app in general. So I suspect you're trying to post a link to a blocked domain.

Comment: I've checked the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.barkside.moodmeter, also tried https://www.facebook.com/MoodMeter. Checked image, loads up fine in post-to-wall dialog.  What is going on!? Other fields are simple text. I'll edit the question with some code.

Comment: @barkside: Sounds like a disconnect between Facebook's policies and Stackoverflow's policies. Have you tried chat? In either case, I think you have a point.